# pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I faced a problem when using pandas to read some txt files.

My file content would look like below.

```
WNS 01.20
57039  108.8833 34.0833   445.8 LC 20150322120000
OOBS
00100 ///// ///// ////// /// /// ////////
00160 216.3 003.7 0006.5 100 100 -1.2E+02
00220 258.9 006.7 0006.6 100 100 -1.3E+02
00280 263.9 007.9 0006.6 100 100 -1.3E+02
```

The first 3 lines are not what I want, so I ignore it. So I read from line "00100", there are some lines without data, and it will show like "////", it could be in any line.

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table(PathofMYFILE, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[0, 1, 2], header=None, comment='/')
```

It works well when the "////" shows not in "00100" (actually the first) line(what I want is if there is "///", just let it be NaN).

However, we can see that in this file, the "///" shows in the first line, and then there is an error:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 411, in _read
data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1005, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1748, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 966, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11884)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 953, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11755)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2184, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:28765)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 7
```

I need some help solving this. I even tried to add `"error_bad_lines=False"` in read_table it doesn't help.

Is there a better way to read these text files. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a couple solutions after saving a `test.txt` file just as the one you copied.

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

def main():
    data = pd.read_table( # this will not fail, but doesn't produce NaNs
        'test.txt', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=range(0,3), header=None,
    )
    print(data)

    # force conversion to numbers on all rows, if it fails fills with NaNs
    data_numeric = data.apply(functools.partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
    print(data_numeric)

    # if you know all values to be read as NaN, you can just pass them...
    # to na_values
    data_with_na = pd.read_table(
        'test.txt', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=range(0,3), header=None,
        na_values=('/////', '//////', '///', '////////')
    )
    print(data_with_na)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Running:

```
     0      1      2       3    4    5         6
0  100  /////  /////  //////  ///  ///  ////////
1  160  216.3  003.7  0006.5  100  100  -1.2E+02
2  220  258.9  006.7  0006.6  100  100  -1.3E+02
3  280  263.9  007.9  0006.6  100  100  -1.3E+02

     0      1    2    3      4      5      6
0  100    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  160  216.3  3.7  6.5  100.0  100.0 -120.0
2  220  258.9  6.7  6.6  100.0  100.0 -130.0
3  280  263.9  7.9  6.6  100.0  100.0 -130.0

     0      1    2    3      4      5      6
0  100    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  160  216.3  3.7  6.5  100.0  100.0 -120.0
2  220  258.9  6.7  6.6  100.0  100.0 -130.0
3  280  263.9  7.9  6.6  100.0  100.0 -130.0
```

All in all, if you know beforehand the `'/'` strings to parse as `NaN`, passing them all to the `na_values` argument of `pd.read_table` should be the best choice.

The `apply(pd.to_numeric)` solution uses a little bit more brute force, although you could limit it to only the rows which contain '/' to make it somewhat better.